# Is std::pmr::new_delete_resource thread safe

Tags: c++, memory, c++17, std

To create a new polymophic_allocator, ppl can use some default resources

```
std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char> newdel { std::pmr::new_delete_resource() };
std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char> synced { std::pmr::synchronized_pool_resource() };
std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char> nonsync { std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource() };
```

My question is the `new_delete_resource` thread-safe?

Comment: The standard says nothing about the thread-safety guarantee on `new_delete_resource()`'s returned `memory_resource`. Thus it would be reasonable to conclude that it's implementation-defined. However, it also does not need to keep any internal state and just delegate the work to the regular `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]`, so I would say it's as thread-safe as those operators themselves, which basically means **thread-safe**. I don't, however, feel confident enough to post this as an answer. I checked GCC's implementation and it is implemented more or less in that (thread-safe) way.